# JDBCPool vs PgPool, unexplained behavior with SSLMODE for postgres

Tags: postgresql, vert.x

We have a RDS postgres instance with **rds.force_ssl** set to true. Using vert.x to connect to the DB and seeing some unexplained behavior which contradicts the sslmode documentation for postgres.

```
// Fails with SSL auth error as expected

PgConnectOptions connectOptions = new PgConnectOptions()
  .setHost(host)
  .setPort(port)
  .setUser(username)
  .setPassword(password)
  .setDatabase(database);
PoolOptions poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(10);

PgPool pgPool = PgPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);
pgPool.getConnection.onSuccess(...).onFailure(...);

// error (note the "SSL off" in the message)
{
  "message": "no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.x.x", user "...", database "...", SSL off", 
  "severity": "FATAL", 
  "code": "28000", 
  "file": "auth.c", 
  "line": "490", 
  "routine": "ClientAuthentication" 
}
```

```
// Works but I expected this to fail since the postgres server is expecting SSL 
// and I am not passing any certs info in connection string.

JsonObject cfg = new JsonObject()
  .put("url", "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database")
  .put("user", username)
  .put("password", password);

JDBCPool jdbcPool = JDBCPool.pool(vertx, cfg);
jdbcClient.getConnection.onSuccess(...).onFailure(...);
```

I have come to the conclusion that using jdbc style urls is doing some magic that makes it work without specifying sslmode. So a couple of questions:

1. Why does jdbc style url work without sslmode? Expected this to throw an exception since the server is forcing ssl connection.
2. Why does NOT using jdbc style url correctly throw SSL error (as expected)? What is PgPool doing different than JDBCPool?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Ran a test with all available values for `sslmode`

```
// ssl error
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname?sslmode=disable

// works
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname?sslmode=allow
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname?sslmode=prefer
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname?sslmode=require
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname?sslmode=verify-ca
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbname?sslmode=verify-full
```

Comment: Best guess is they are using different settings for [SSL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html#nonvalidating). From here [vert.x SSL](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/#_using_ssltls) it says the connection will use `env` variables e.g. `PGSSLMODE`, so you might to check if that is set. AFAIK, the Postgres JDBC driver itself does not use those `env` variables.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver `PGSSLMODE` is definitely not set. I debugged through the code which picks up `DISABLE` as the default sslmode which causes the auth error to be thrown correctly. I have read the documents you referenced several times but still not clear. Thank you for responding.

Comment: Time to look at the Postgres logs.  Make sure the server is configured to log connections/disconnection per here [Config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) and restart if server if you have to change. You might also want to try logging in with `psql` to see what you get. That will eliminate some layers and set a base line for what you can do.

Comment: Unfortunately no access to postgres instance. Will work with a DBA to get the logs. `psql` correctly shows SSL in use: `SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)`. As per the doc, `psql` uses `libpq` which defaults to non-validating SSL connection (whatever that means).

Comment: non-validating means it does not validate the authenticity of the server via server certificate. Look  here [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) and search for `sslmode` to see what the options are.

Comment: Sorry but then what's the point of using SSL if server certificates are not validated? From the doc, it seems jdbc is trying the default `prefer` which says `first try an SSL connection; if that fails, try a non-SSL connection`. Running a test trying all ssl modes and see if the output helps narrow this down.

Comment: Because it creates an encrypted connection. If you control both ends of the connection and you want the part that crosses public space to be encrypted then it is a viable option.

Comment: Oh that explains why the doc says `prefer` mode does not protect from MITM. Thanks Adrian.

Comment: This link [SSL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html#nonvalidating) I sent earlier has a table that lays out the security ramifications of each mode well.

Comment: Updated the post with the test runs.

Comment: So now you know what URL to use to connect with.

Comment: I knew what URL to use. Just wasn't able to understand WHY it was working.